# How to handle circular Dispose() in C#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, dispose, circular-dependency

When I have a circular dependency between two `IDisposable` objects that rely on each other and should also propagate disposal to each other, how shall I best avoid a `StackOverflowException` from an infinite recursion in the `Dispose()` method?

My initial guess would be saving and checking whether the object has already had its `Dispose()` method called up in the call stack and early exit in this case, like I do here in my example implementation:

```
using CircularDispose;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

Example a = new(nameof(a));
Example b = new(nameof(b));

a.Other = b;
b.Other = a;

Console.WriteLine("Start");

a.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(a)} is disposed: {a.IsDisposed}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(b)} is disposed: {b.IsDisposed}");

Console.WriteLine("Finished");

namespace CircularDispose
{
    [PublicAPI]
    public class Example : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _isDisposing;
        private string _name;

        public Example? Other { get; set; }

        public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

        public Example(string name) => _name = name;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            Dispose(true);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_name}.{nameof(Dispose)}({disposing}) was called");

            if (!_isDisposing && !IsDisposed)
            {
                _isDisposing = true;

                if (disposing)
                {
                    DisposeManagedResources();
                }

                DisposeUnmanagedResources();

                IsDisposed = true;
            }
        }

        ~Example()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        [PublicAPI]
        protected virtual void DisposeUnmanagedResources()
        {
            // dispose unmanaged resources
        }

        [PublicAPI]
        protected virtual void DisposeManagedResources()
        {
            Other?.Dispose();
            Other = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not find such an implementation in a quick google search though, so I wonder whether it is OK to do, save and fine and all.

Program output is:

```
Start
a.Dispose(True) was called
b.Dispose(True) was called
a.Dispose(True) was called
a is disposed: True
b is disposed: True
Finished
```

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: This is absolutely classic approach to check some kind of "already been disposed" flag in the beginning of the `Dispose` method. So, you sample code is totally ok.

Comment: You probably don't need the `_isDisposing`. Just use `IsDisposed` and set it to `true` at the beginning of the disposal process. Because once the disposing process started the object should be considered disposed and its usage should be disallowed.

Comment: Seems ok, I would set `IsDisposed` to true at start of the method and removed the second flag.

Comment: Why are you afraid of recursion? If your implementors call `this.Dispose()` again in either overridable method, that's on them... You could do so with any such pattern.

Comment: @CodeCaster infinite recursion would occur in this example if I would not set and check for the ```_isDisposing``` flag - not on a single object, but by ping-ponging the call to ```Other?.Dispose()``` - which as per the question is a requirement

Comment: I don't get it, ehy would the Other call Dispose on the caller again?

Comment: @Artur I just noticed that all examples I saw online, like [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) set the flag after disposal has been finished. So I thought this might be the more expected thing to do, e.g. in case somebody would like to check for whether disposing has finished down the call stack. But since most people seem to expect ```IsDisposed``` to be false also during the disposal process, I will use this instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure would, since the are circularly referencing each other, and use the same class. This is of course only necessary if you have this circular reference and no hierarchy.

Comment: I think it was too early for me, I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, the solution isn't too bad. However, it can be simplified a bit, removing the need for the extra `_isDisposing` field:

```cs
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_name}.{nameof(Dispose)}({disposing}) was called");

            if (!IsDisposed)
            {
                IsDisposed = true;

                if (disposing)
                {
                    DisposeManagedResources();
                }

                DisposeUnmanagedResources();
            }
        }
```

If memory consumption is an issue (e.g. because you have *a lot* of instances of the class), a trick is to reuse an existing variable that's already used in the `DisposeManagedResources()` part, such as the `Other` variable in your case. If it's null, Dispose has already been called (or is not necessary). `DisposeUnmanagedResources()` should never be circular, because then you would be touching something that is not an unmanaged resource, so it could also be outside the `if`.

Comment: But ```DisposeUnmanagedResources()``` is called from the ```Dispose(bool)``` method which may be called multiple times, right? Even if ```DisposeUnmanagedResources()``` is implemented to be save to call multiple times, leaving it in the branch seems more intuitive and performant to me? (also [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) early exit before doing disposal of unmanaged resources)

Comment: Of course, you would set the unmanaged pointers or handles you use to Null / Invalid after disposing them and check their validity before clearing them. But unless you have a large number of unmanaged fields (which is _very_ rare) the additional performance impact of an additional null test is negligible.